# Problema com UPDATE do android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

Estou com um problema na hora de dar `update` em uma tabela no `Android/SqLite`:

Tentei das duas formas que encontrei:

```
String query = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET VALUE1='VALUE1'... WHERE KEY_ID = KEY_ID"
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL(query);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("VALUE1",VALUE1);
.
.
.
db.update("MY_TABLE",values,"KEY_ID="+KEY_ID,null);
```

Nenhuma das duas formas está dando erro, compilam normalmente mas o valores não são atualizados no banco de dados. Já debuguei a aplicação e os valores estão chegando corretamente no método, mas, simplesmente não atualiza. Quando recupero os dados novamente estão sem as modificações. Alguém sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: na primeira forma, tenta fazer: `query = "commit;"; db.execSQL(query);`

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction.

Comment: retornou esse erro ai, quando tentei dar um commit

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
db.update("MY_TABLE", values, "KEY_ID = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(KEY_ID)});
```

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

> Você pode incluir ?  na cláusula WHERE, que será substituído pelos
>   valores do quarto parametro. Os valores serão vinculados como Strings.

Comment: Sim eu consigo incluir e buscar normalmente no banco! Tentei dessa forma ai e ainda não foi!

Comment: Você fecha a conexão?  **db.close ()** ?

Comment: Veja qual o valor que o **update** retorna. Se for **1** é porque a linha foi afetada

Comment: bom, funcionou... eu realmente não estava fechando a conexão, mas não acho que faça muito sentido não esta funcionando por conta disso! Mas mesmo assim muito obrigado, resolveu o problema, depois quando tiver mais tempo vou pesquisar sobre isso! valeu mesmo!